# Integer.parseint exceptions

Tags: java

The question was :
Write a program that processes an input.txt file that contains data regarding ticket type followed by mileage covered and reports how many frequent-flier miles the person earns.

- 1 frequent flyer mile is earned for each mile traveled in coach.
- 2 frequent flyer miles are earned for each mile traveled in first class.
- 0 frequent flyer miles are earned on a discounted flight.

For example, given the data in input.txt below, your method must return 15600 (2*5000 + 1500 + 100 + 2*2000).

Input.txt:

```
firstclass 5000 coach 1500 coach
100 firstclass 2000 discount 300
```

My code gives me a problem with the parseint method. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
//InInteger class
import java.lang.NumberFormatException;
public class IsInteger {

public static  boolean IsaInteger (String s)throws  NumberFormatException 
{
    try
    {
        Integer.parseInt(s);//converts the string into an integer
        return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

}

//main class

import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class LA5ex2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


BufferedReader input= new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (new FileInputStream("C:/Users/user/workspace/LA5ex2/input.txt")));
    String str;
    int TotalMiles=0;
    try {
        int mileage,lines=0;
         String check,copy=null;
         String word=null;
         boolean isString=false;

        while ((str = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            lines++;
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(str);
            while (token.hasMoreTokens()) 
            {
                if ((lines>1) && (isString))
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
                else    
                {word= token.nextToken();
                copy=word;}
              if (token.hasMoreTokens())
                  mileage= Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
              else
              {
                  if (!(IsInteger.IsaInteger(word)))
                  {
                      copy=word;
                      isString=true;
                  }

                  break;
              }
            if (copy.equals("firstclass"))
                TotalMiles+= (2*mileage);
            else if (copy.equals("coach"))
                TotalMiles+= (1*mileage);
            else if (copy.equals("discount"))
            TotalMiles+= (0*mileage);
            }
        }


System.out.println("Frequent-flier miles the person earns: "+ TotalMiles);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: "My code gives me a problem with the parseint method" - what problem, and with what input?

Comment: What is the error you see?

Comment: I re-formatted your input.txt file contents to be more readable but I wasn't sure if each pair of data (flight type & miles traveled) should be on a new line or not. Please update accordingly.

Comment: they should be on the next line, and thats the trick here !

Comment: To be specific, the error is in the IsaInteger class where it throws a NumberFormatException when it accepts the "firstclass" string of the second line. I dont know why does the program stop running when I have a catch statement in the program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the stacktrace that I get when running your code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "firstclass"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
    at LA5ex2.main(LA5ex2.java:30)
```

I assume this is the error that you mention in your comment. However, the `NumberFormatException` does not occur in your `IsaInteger()` method in the `IsInteger` class (where you try-catch it by returning `true` or `false`), but in the `LA5ex2` class (where you also try-catch it, but if it crashes, only the stacktrace gets printed). The exception occurs when `Integer.parseInt()` tries to parse the string `firstclass` as an integer, which of course fails:

```
if(token.hasMoreTokens()) mileage = Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
```

---

I rewrote your code in `LA5ex2.java` with two `ArrayList`s (to keep track of the various flier classes and the various mileages) using your `IsaInteger` method:
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;

```
public class LA5ex2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input.txt")));
        String str = null;
        String token = null;
        int totalMiles = 0;
        int lines = 0;
        ArrayList<String> flierClasses = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> mileages = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        try {
            while((str = input.readLine()) != null) {
                lines++; // Why are we counting the lines, anyway?
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str);
                while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    token = tokenizer.nextToken();

                    if(!(IsInteger.IsaInteger(token))) {
                        flierClasses.add(token); // if it's not an int, we assume it's a flier class
                    } else {
                        mileages.add(Integer.parseInt(token)); // if it's an int, it's a mileage
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Add everything up
        for(int i = 0; i < flierClasses.size(); i++) {
            totalMiles += calculateFlierMiles(flierClasses.get(i), mileages.get(i));
        }

        System.out.println("Frequent-flier miles the person earns: " + totalMiles);
    }

    private static int calculateFlierMiles(final String flierClass, final int mileage) {
        if(flierClass.equals("firstclass")) return(2 * mileage);
        else if(flierClass.equals("coach")) return(1 * mileage);
        else if(flierClass.equals("discount")) return(0 * mileage);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This code gives me the desired output: `Frequent-flier miles the person earns: 15600`

Comment: @user3367892 If my answer solves your problem, I'd be happy if you mark it as "accepted answer" and/or vote it up :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the problem is in `IsaInteger` (which should be stylized as `isAnInteger`). In that case, add a line that prints out the value of `s` before the try/catch and tell me what you get.

Also, why are you using tokens when you could use a `BufferedReader` and its `nextLine()` method?

Comment: The program doesn't run even after adding this because there still is a problem with this function.

Comment: however I found out that its the string "firstclass" of the second line where it stops working

Comment: Can you paste the error message and the line on which it is occurring?

Comment: @user3367892 "problem" could be really many things (does not compile, does not return the expected value, throws an exception at runtime, etc.). You need to be more specific.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "firstclass"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at LA5ex2.main(LA5ex2.java:35)

Comment: I am using a bufferedreader here but nextLine() method reads line by line, I want to read word by word.

Comment: To be specific, the error is in the IsaInteger class where it throws a NumberFormatException when it accepts the "firstclass" string of the second line. I dont know why does the program stop running when I have a catch statement in the program ?

Comment: You can either use `next()` to read each word or split at the space with `split(String)`